# Is it grammatical to say "What would that be"?

Tags: grammar

I understand the basic rules to convert a statement to a question, for instance,

> That is a cat.
>
> What is that?

the grammar pattern is `what + be + pronoun`.

In one of my posts ([Is "the first time" a type of signposting language or something like that?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/240782/109190)) I said

> "distinct episodes (times)" from what? some other kind of episodes (times)? **What would that be**?

A complete form of that would be

> What kind of episodes **would that be**?

I see lots of people use this kind of expression. Is it grammatical? If yes what is the grammar pattern?

Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is perfectly grammatical.

When we ask a question with a wh-word that isn't the subject, we invert the verb and the subject, eg

> What is that?
>
> Where are you?

When there is an auxiliary (which there always is for a question, unless the verb is *be* or - for some users - *have*), we invert the subject and the auxiliary, but the main verb follows after:

> What would that be?
>
> What will you do?
>
> When should I go?

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive explanation. And "what am I going to do" comes from the same way, right?

Comment: @WXJ96163: Yes. I could have been more precise and say that only the first auxiliary precedes the subject: all the rest of the verb string (however many modals and auxililaries that is) follows: _What might you have been going to say?_